# android sqlite: cursor from database query returns empty but shouldn't

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to filter a listview on buttonclick but my database query returns an empty cursor. I can't find where the problem is. Does someone know why the cursor returns empty?

Here is my code:

```
private void initSearch() {
    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

    ImageButton searchEntry = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_search_entry);
    searchEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.startAnimation(buttonAnimation);
            String catchword = searchText.toString();
            if (catchword.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, noCatchword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Cursor match = myDb.getWordMatches(catchword); //cursor is empty

                cursorAdapter.swapCursor(match);
                cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the database method:

```
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query) {
    //Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COL_HEAD+ " = '%" +query+"%' OR " +COL_TEXT+ " = '%"+query+"%'", null);
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COL_HEAD+ " LIKE ? OR "+COL_TEXT+ " LIKE ?", new String[]{query});
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

I've tried both queries as you can see but both return an empty cursor. 
The rows are correctly inserted in my database as everything else works fine, so this can not be the reason for my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `"%"+query+"%"` in your `selectionArgs`

Comment: have you tried manually executing your SQL statement directly into your DB's command interface?

Comment: @pskink: still returns empty cursor

Comment: Try this `Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COL_HEAD+ " LIKE ? OR "+COL_TEXT+ " LIKE ?", new String[]{query,query});`

Comment: @user1506104 no I don't know how that works

Comment: so follow the comment above (from user1506104)

Comment: @AnkitaShah doesn't work either

Comment: try a very simple query first to see if you have data in your database: Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME);

Comment: @user1506104 I have data in my database. It is being displayed in a listview.

Comment: do not try blindly experiment with your `rawQuery`: instead start experimenting with `sqlite3` tool on your device - it is much more faster

Comment: and try to hardcode your query in one single string instead of using variables to check such as `database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  table_name WHERE col_name LIKE value1 OR col_name LIKE value2"`

Comment: try like this..     Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE "+COL_HEAD+ " like = '%" +query+"%' OR " +COL_TEXT+ " like = '%"+query+"%'", null);

Comment: @brahmyadigopula I already tried that... also not working :(

Comment: what is in the error log cat?

Comment: did you try [sqlite3](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html) tool ?

Comment: @brahmyadigopula there is no error. cursor.moveToFirst(); just returns false which means it is empty

Comment: @pskink no I didn't. I'll try that later.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using `getText().toString();`. As in this line:

```
String catchword = searchText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That was the problem. Now the cursor is returned with the right content. :)

Comment: Glad I could help :D